# Numers of walks on non rectangular grid for some box

Tags: combinatorics

Let $G$ be a non rectangular grid and let $S$ be a square on the graph. Given a box $b\in S$, I want to find the number of walks (where each step is up or right) on grid from the lowest box in the column of $b$ to the rightmost box in the row of $b$ (lowest box in column and rightmost box not have to be in $S$).

For example, Let $G$ be the following grid and $S$ is marked in red. I want to find the corresponding number for the box $b$ which is marked (should be $2$):
[image]

How can I find the required value? the question applies for any $b\in S$.
BTW, the values in $S$ (starting at top left box and going clockwise) are $3,2,1,1$.

I have no clue how to begin...
Thanks!

Comment: This question is not very clear. Is it about this particular illustration, or a general question? What can a "non rectangular grid" be (triangular for instance)?. What's the point of $S$? the question seems to depend on $G$ and $b$ only.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, It is a general question. Non rectangular grid means that we have a rectangular grid and we remove some of the squares. I forgot to mention that $S$ is the biggest square in $G$ that include the top left square. Thank you!

Comment: and explain further the evolution of ur sequence